# Foundation Top-Bar Glitch with has dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am having an issue with top-bar. Below is a copy of the li I am having issues with.  The problem is that when The link is clicked it changes the size of top-bar by adding `style="height:180"` to the top bar and adding `not-click moved` to the `li` below. It is also removing `::after` from the link when clicked as well.  This is breaking the website and I cant seem to figure out why.

```
<li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Description</a>
    <ul class="dropdown"> 
        <li><a href="filename.php">Description</a></li>
        <li><a href="filename.php">Description</a></li>
        <li><a href="filename.php">Description</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Make a Fiddle, we need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a jQuery event handler somewhere that is adding those properties to the `li` when it's clicked.

One other theory is that it might be your css properties for the clicked `li` that are specified in your `foundation_and_overrides.scss` file or some other css/scss file.